ng-update schematic - object property migration
I'm currently working on an implementation for an ng-update schematic for our internal design system. We have components and interfaces that are renamed between 2 versions of our package. The interfaces sometimes also have renamed properties.
I'm using the createMigrationSchematicRule method from the @angular/cdk package. I'm providing the following update data to the migration method:
{
  attributeSelectors: {},
  classNames: {
    [TargetVersion.V17]: [
      {
        pr: '',
        changes: [{ replace: 'Site', replaceWith: 'AppCenterSubject' }]
      }
    ]
  },
  constructorChecks: {},
  cssSelectors: {},
  elementSelectors: {},
  inputNames: {},
  methodCallChecks: {},
  outputNames: {},
  propertyNames: {
    [TargetVersion.V17]: [
      {
        pr: '',
        changes: [
          {
            replace: 'site',
            replaceWith: 'name',
            limitedTo: { classes: ['Site'] }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  symbolRemoval: {}
}

When I'm running my schematic on this component:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public value: Site = {
    site: 'Site',
    group: 'Group'
  };
}

I get the following output:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public value: AppCenterSubject = {
    site: 'Site',
    group: 'Group'
  };
}

So the Site interface is migrated to the new AppCenterSubject interface, but the site property of the value object is not migrated to the new name property. Am I missing something, or is this just not possible at all?
